# Timing a Process (Windows 7 DOS Prompt)

Tags: c++, time, command, dos

I am running a C++ program and want to know how much time it takes. I can do it with in-built functions in the header files time.h and Windows.h but I want to use something like "time" command in UNIX. The reason is because my program is redirecting the output to a text file which is 750 MB and I am in no mood of trying to open it. How can that be done in Windows 7 (DOS prompt).

Thanks

Varun

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can capturing the time before and after using `echo %TIME%`, or there are some free utilities for this purpose.  For example, check out the stopwatch program from this link.  It only has accuracy down to the second, unfortunately,

http://www.jfitz.com/dos/index.html

Also refer to this similar question.  There are some good solutions in here including a batch file that uses `set /A` to parse `echo %TIME%`,

[Print time in a batch file (milliseconds)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605522/print-time-in-a-batch-file-milliseconds)

Answer (score 1):

I've been using this for quite a while (long enough that it was originally written for MS-DOS). It always writes the timing output to stderr, so it goes to the console even when/if standard output is directed to a file. In theory, you could write it directly to a console separate from standard error, but I've never needed it so I've never done it.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <process.h>
#include <malloc.h>
#include <string.h>
#if defined(WIN32) || defined(_WIN32)
#include <windows.h>
#else
#include <dos.h>
#endif

int main(void) {

    clock_t start, end;
    char *cmd;
#ifdef WIN32
    char *cmd_line = strdup(GetCommandLine());
#else
    char *cmd_line = 0x80;
#endif
    int seconds, tenths;
    char seps[] = " \r\n\t/";

    _heapmin();

    strtok(cmd_line, seps);

    cmd_line = strtok(NULL, "");

    start = clock();
    system(cmd_line);
    end = clock();

    cmd = strtok(cmd_line, seps );

    seconds = (end-start) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
    tenths = (end-start) / ( CLOCKS_PER_SEC / 10 );
    tenths -= seconds * 10;

    fprintf(stderr, "\n`%s' took %d.%d seconds.\n", cmd, seconds, tenths);
    return 0;
}
```

Note that naming the result `time.exe` will *not* produce correct results (`time` is a command built into the shell, so it'll never run). I normally name it "timer" instead.